# use variable to create an Object literal, how to get just its value

Tags: javascript, object-literal

can you explain why this Object gets both variable/value instead of just its value?

```
var a = 'foo', b = 'bar', obj = {a, b};
```

expected

```
obj = {'foo' : 'bar'}
```

result

```
obj = {a: "foo", b: "bar"}
```

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In ES5 JavaScript, your code would be a syntax error.

In ES2015 JavaScript,

```
var obj = {a, b}
```

is shorthand for

```
var obj = { a: a, b: b }
```

If you want `{foo: "bar"}` you can (in ES2015) use

```
var obj = { [a]: b }
```

For compatibility with older environments, you'd have to use two statements:

```
var obj = {};
obj[a] = b;
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is, you are adding them as two variables, members and not a key-value pair. It is **expected** result (ES6 / ES2015) or **Syntax Error** (ES5, as there should be a key: value pair separated by comma). What you are looking for is:

```
obj = {};
abj[a] = b;
```

The interesting thing to note that is, giving:

```
obj = {a: b};
```

Will take `a` as the new key and not substitute with the value of `a`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following code:

```
obj[a] = b;
```

This will give you:

obj = { "foo" : "bar" }

Your original way of doing it is just shorthand and passing in the variables to the object, not just their values